# To do a Agora.io voice call do you have to be in the app you are calling from?

Tags: agora.io

I want to use Agora.io in my application, but i want to know does the user have to be logged in to the application in order to receive the call or does Agora.io call the phone and not through the app?

Answer (score 3):

Agora's engine does not implement direct calling functionality. Agora supports two or more users joining a "channel" but both have to be using the app), but Agora does not support push notifications in their SDK.

You will need to use a service for push notifications (*when user isn't in-app*), CallKit (*iOS*) or ConnectionService (*Android*) for the phone-call UI.

**[Update]**

Agora has a demo showing how to use Agora's Real-Time Messaging along with the native ConnectionService/CallKit to implement a "call" feature using Agora.

Android: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling/tree/master/OpenDuo-Android

IOS: https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling/tree/master/OpenDuo-iOS

Comment: Can you please share code snippet of implementing this.,

Comment: @ManoharPerepa I have updated my response with links to demos

Comment: @Hermes it shows that the website can't be found. Do you have an updated link?

Comment: @Jaqueline the repo has been moved to here https://github.com/AgoraIO-Usecase/Video-Calling, also updated my response to include the latest urls for each platform.